# Can I safely use domain in URI

Tags: javascript, php, uri

I am getting the hostname using javascript:

```
var url = window.location.hostname;
```

Can I then safely (and correctly) use this as part of a url, or should I do something to it first?

```
var newUrl = 'http://domain.com/file.php?url='+url;
```

In the php file I will get said url using $_GET (and verify validity of domain name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need to encode it so that you can use it in a url:

```
var newUrl = 'http://domain.com/file.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Note that you don't have to change anything on the server-side, `$_GET['url']` is already decoded.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you